# Looking for tutorials to achieve this look

Tags: adobe-photoshop, style-identification, style

I would like to learn how to achieve the look shown in this picture

[image]
[**Source**](https://www.shutterstock.com/it/image-photo/dolomites-alps-mountain-val-di-funes-291135272)

I can't find any tutorials because I don't even know how to name the style itself (I tried "cartoon like" or something similar but found very different styles)

Comment: That looks like a real image to me, what is the image that you're working with to try to reproduce a similar effect?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I think it is a real image too, but it seems to have that kind of look, I hardly find a way to describe it ... like a 3D painting, like those wonderful graffiti which seem to have depth ... probably it is a clever use of dodge and burning plus Orton effect ... I'll post soon (I don't have it now) an example of landscape picture that I took and would like to edit that way, if possible. Thanks again!

Comment: I think that *that* look has to be done when taking the photo not in post production, but I may be wrong.

Comment: This might be a photobash of a few photos - backdrop mountains looks slightly out of place in contrast to a mountains in foreground... At least in my opinion. But this is a pure speculation at this point, and I can't recommend anything besides some photobashing techniques to essentialy "make" this photo from a few others - then apply overall effects, like D&B and Orton's.

Answer (score 1):

## Hyper realistic landscape

Several results appear searching [Hyper realistic landscape photo editing](https://www.google.es/search?q=hyper%20realistic%20landscape%20photo%20editing&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CYR3bRFNa1zyIjiux6XoBpvXjMlgo7t7UHiZdZWIuLY-pkQDnPE-CLxcfs8A-hShO38WFxqvLb46cFzLNMyb1inIlyoSCa7HpegGm9eMESj4lT8b_1uZDKhIJyWCju3tQeJkRr-kv0UkVzMQqEgl1lYi4tj6mRBGXhMRyc9rqTSoSCQOc8T4IvFx-EbXSo8wsOVlBKhIJzwD6FKE7fxYRMDLr5bsJ8FEqEgkXGq8tvjpwXBE8oxnj6Bj6YioSCcs0zJvWKciXEWVKrOZ93XPm&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ3dzTk97eAhVDdhoKHUqoDYkQ9C96BAgBEBs).

[image: landscape photo editing]

Comment: Dear Danielillo, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Open in Camera Raw and increase contrast, whites, saturation and clarity.